# Change multiple elements simultaneously

Tags: reactjs

I have a button which upon clicking, should make the password field blank. I also intend to change the text of the button from Change Password to Save password at the same time. In short, I would like these changes to happen at the same time. I have taken a toggle variable using which I'm able to change the text of the button but do not know how to do the same for the password field.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";



const User = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState()
    const [password, setPassword] = useState()
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    const history = useHistory();

    const login = () => {


        // if (username === 'admin' & password === 'admin') {
        //      history.push('/home')
        // } else {

        //     alert('wrong credentials')

        // }
        setToggle(!toggle);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <label for="username">UserName:</label>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    id="username"
                    name="username"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(evt) => setUsername(evt.target.value)}
                />
                <br />

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(evt) => setPassword(evt.target.value)}
                />
                <button className="btn btn-primary mt-5 " onClick={login}>{toggle ? 'SavePassword' : ' change password '}</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary mt-5  ml-5  pull-right" onClick={login}>Log out</button>

            </div>
        </>
    )

}
export default User;
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding `setPassword('');` to your login function?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-river-svygj?file=/src/User.js

Answer (score 0):

Fastest answer is:

```
const login = () => {
   setPassword('');
   setToggle(!toggle);
}
```

This solution has a problem: every time you run `login` function your component is re-rendered twice.

To avoid this, there are several ways; the first one could be join `username, password and toggle` into the same state. Something like:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
   username: null,
   password: null,
   toggle: false
});
...
const login = () => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return {
         toggle: !prevState.toggle,
         username: prevState.username
         password: "",
      }
    });
}
```